# Installing Heroku Toolbelt on Windows 10

Tags: bash, powershell, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've been having some issues installing the Heroku toolbelt on Windows 10, 64-bit.

It's the first time I install Heroku. I downloaded it from https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows.

After installing, I tried launching a new Git Bash and typing `heroku login` but what I got back was `bash: heroku: command not found`

Running the same command on Windows Powershell, what I got back was

```
'MYSQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'MYSQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any suggestions? I thought that googling those lines would help, but I haven't found much.

I followed the recommendation from [here](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/heroku-installation-error/1149), but now when typing `heroku login` on the Powershell, nothing happens. Nothing changes on the Git Bash.

I checked, and the Heroku folder was added to the PATH.

I thought I'd ask for some help before installing anything else.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try a restart?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin\heroku.cmd" login` worked for me (Windows 10, standard command line)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> bash: heroku: command not found

The error message is clear: Bash cannot find the `heroku` command, it's *not* on your `PATH`.

> I checked, and the Heroku folder was added to the PATH.

It seems you didn't check it correctly.
Note that even if it looks correct in the `PATH` settings window,
Git Bash might have a different `PATH` configured.
To see the `PATH` in Git Bash, run:

```
echo $PATH
```

When debugging path issues,
it's best to first run `heroku` with the absolute path. For example if it's in `C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin\heroku` then you can run in Git Bash with:

```
/c/Program\ Files/Heroku/bin/heroku login
```

If this works (and it should),
then you can add it to `PATH` like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Heroku/bin"
```

Note that Heroku will likely need other programs too on the `PATH`,
such as MySQL and Ruby.
Find their absolute paths,
and add there directories to `PATH` the same way as `heroku` itself in the above example.

If instead of Git Bash,
you want to work in CMD,
the procedure is the same,
but the syntax to print and set `PATH` is different:

```
echo %PATH%
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;%PATH%"
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119042/discussion-between-janos-and-umair-shah-yousafzai).

Comment: I still get the error  @echo: not found and a few others even when I enter the full path `/c/Program\ Files/Heroku/bin/heroku login` in git Bash. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

In windows bash instead of this

```
PATH="$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Heroku/bin"
```

use this

```
 PATH="$PATH:/c/Program Files/Heroku/bin"
```

Answer (score 4):

My working solution (for **git-bash** especially) is:

```
alias heroku='winpty `where heroku.cmd`'
```

stored in .bashrc in home user dir
and them

```
heroku
```

works as expected

Comment: It's an answer for "bash: heroku: command not found" in Windows 10 git-bash [tested on  4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys), from git 2.16.2.windows.1] and toolbelt heroku [heroku-cli/6.15.31-958455a (win32-x64) node-v9.3.0] and here I'm using `where heroku.cmd` but it can by abs path like /c/Program\ Files/Heroku/binb/heroku.cmd for better performance

Answer (score 1):

If using bash from VSCode, I had to restart VSCode, after installing heroku. If not using VSCode, you probably need to restart your bash terminal, after installing heroku.

Answer (score 0):

In `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` (if you are using Windows), go to `Advanced system settings`, and there in `Environment Variables`, you'll find two lists, on the same window, viz. `System variables`, and `User variables for your system`. Make sure you add your path, viz. `C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin`, in both of these lists.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread and just want to share my solution.

Edit **.bashrc** for git-bash

```
alias heroku='"C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin\heroku.cmd" $@'
```