# Installed Heroku but not recognised

Tags: heroku, installation

I installed git and Heroku on my Windows8.1 64bit machine. On running:heroku --version I get the following error:
bash: heroku: command not found

What must I do to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Heroku Toolbelt on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908177/installing-heroku-toolbelt-on-windows-10)

---

> bash: heroku: command not found

The error message is clear: Bash cannot find the `heroku` command, it's *not* on your `PATH`.

> I checked, and the Heroku folder was added to the PATH.

It seems you didn't check it correctly.
Note that even if it looks correct in the `PATH` settings window,
Git Bash might have a different `PATH` configured.
To see the `PATH` in Git Bash, run:

```
echo $PATH
```

When debugging path issues,
it's best to first run `heroku` with the absolute path. For example if it's in `C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin\heroku` then you can run in Git Bash with:

```
/c/Program\ Files/Heroku/bin/heroku login
```

If this works (and it should),
then you can add it to `PATH` like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Heroku/bin"
```

Note that Heroku will likely need other programs too on the `PATH`,
such as MySQL and Ruby.
Find their absolute paths,
and add there directories to `PATH` the same way as `heroku` itself in the above example.

If instead of Git Bash,
you want to work in CMD,
the procedure is the same,
but the syntax to print and set `PATH` is different:

```
echo %PATH%
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;%PATH%"
```